# how to set license key to php applications...so that it cant be used on several machines?

Tags: php

I am new in PHP development and I was wondering is there any way to prevent the PHP application I developed to be installed on multiple computers after I sell it to clients? I was to make a licensing system which will prevent the application from running on multiple computers except for the one on which I will install it on.

Comment: You can use [Ion Cube](http://www.ioncube.com/) and some sort of "ping to remote server to keep alive" sort of thing. But overall it just ads complexity. Long story short, there's no sure way to make sure that they don't get installed on multiple computers.

Comment: `Can i find any cracks for it? ` Read your question slowly, then read your comment slowly...